# Referencing External Library in YAML File

Tags: java, gradle, yaml, openapi

I have a Gradle *project* (not using SpringBoot) that has a YAML file with a directory structure of:

**project/folderA/folderB/exampleFile.yaml**

exampleFile.yaml --> is used for the swagger spec page of this *project*, and uses `$ref` to point to files for creating it's swagger definition

How would I make `$ref` point to YAML files that are held in an External Library (aka files from a project that are part of my project's dependencies)? I'm not sure how I'd build the path, in `$ref`, to reach an external library since the external library isn't part of the project's direct directory structure

[The OpenAPI documentation specifies many scenarios in which we can use $ref](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/), but one I'm not seeing is how to extract/reference YAML files from an inherited project. Is there YAML-file syntax that'll achieve this?

I've tried looking this up but I'm not sure what the path would look like to make this reference, especially since the server where this project will be held might have a different root directory where it is fetching loaded External Library contents, compared to what that reference path looks like in my local machine

Comment: In the external library, it provides a Swagger/OAS spec in the JAR itself?

Comment: @Cisco The swagger page for this service is generated by exampleFile.yaml, but exampleFile.yaml has $ref's to other YAML files. The other YAML files need to be pulled from a dependency (External Library in the IDE) that has a host of YAML files that will be used to fullfill the swagger spec